# One ... Another .... Neither

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis, determiners, parallelism

Does the following work?

> **One** of his friends is from Japan, and **another** from France. **Neither** can speak German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the example text is close-enough to grammatically correct.  The following text would be slightly better:

> One of his friends is from Japan, and another is from France. Neither can speak German.

This is short for:

> One of his friends is from Japan, and another [friend] is from France. Neither [friend] can speak German.

or:

> One of his friends is from Japan, and another [of his friends] is from France. Neither [of these two friends] can speak German.

Comment: I find the OP's sentence fine without the extra _is_.